# How to verify method calls in where clause of spock test for a recursive method

Tags: groovy, spock

Let's say my class is Foo with a recursive method bar which calls a service like below

```
public class Foo
{
    private DataService service;

    public void perform(int count, final SomeObject obj)
    {
        if(count > 0)
        {
            service.refresh(obj);
            count = count- 1;
            perform(count, obj)
        }
    }

}
```

Now I want to verify number of times refresh method gets called for differnt input, something like this

```
@Test
def "test method"()
{
given:
def obj = Mock(SomeObject)

expect:
foo.perform(refreshRequests, inputObj)

where:
refreshRequests | inputObj | 
1               | obj      | 1 * service.refresh(obj)
2               | obj      | 2 * service.refresh(obj)
}
```

Is there a way to achieve something like this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, this is how you do it. You basically just move the interaction to the `then` block where it belongs, and use the `refreshRequests` as expected invocation count.

`refreshRequests * service.refresh(inputObj)`

The full runnable example with some minor modifications.

```
public class Foo
{
    private DataService service;

    public void perform(int count, String obj)
    {
        if(count > 0)
        {
            service.refresh(obj);
            count = count- 1;
            perform(count, obj)
        }
    }
}

interface DataService {
    void refresh(String aString)
}

class ASpec extends spock.lang.Specification {

    def "test method"()    {
        given:
        def service = Mock(DataService)
        Foo foo = new Foo(service: service)

        when:
        foo.perform(refreshRequests, inputObj)

        then:
        refreshRequests * service.refresh(inputObj)

        where:
        refreshRequests | inputObj 
        1               | "a" 
        2               | "b"     
    }
}
```

Try it in the [groovy web console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?codez=eJx9UcFugzAMvecrLE4wdWjdsVUnTZp2myaNLwjBQDaasCTQSWv_fQkB2pSpliAQv_f8bLdd3nAGrKFaw6uU5JeAjVbxnhqEF2pohqrnDEH7c0s8whN7yQtoUZVS7WMuDDDZCbOCzCguKpD5ZzLAvawLXsYDBp7gIZlvz3kXY6lUYalQ17GT2QYIL7Hz5z2sw-xkaDQzu3BxIv59IsT6tUDKwj69laGxqf7YDfVn4rh-Ys9Ziwzwx6AoNOhWsq-0oaJK3T0vOaOGS2ElB80CS4gMagN7NLUsojgJe694j2ITtOI44zhsu2-2QHxhNgmwdn9Q2mcHAg_uLx6Zm0kiITPhUF-XstR0mtzY-Qd-d9avXgEXbWfe3SBnjlkoXLHgbrHJf2SsEYW3dY5zeZhxawjjCBGNzunHZTqPhq_z_i_zfw4y1FY).